# pad the string with whitespaces to make it of certain length in xquery osb 12 c

Tags: xquery, oracle12c, esb, soa, osb

I want to pad a string with whitespaces to make it of certain length in XQuery on the OSB platform.

I tried `string-join` and `concat`, but none of them pad whitespaces as they consider them as empty string.

**Sample input:**

```
<root-element xmlns="">
   <string-to-pad>abc</string-to-pad>
</root-element>

**Expected output:**

<root-element>
<paddedString>abc  </paddedString>
</root-element>
```

Comment: You'll need to post the relevant code here first along with what you have tried so far

Comment: Actually, the string-join and concat were adding the space but Oracle Jdeveloper was not showing it.

Answer (score 1):

Yes not much to say without a code sample. This is how the [functx library](http://www.xqueryfunctions.com/xq/functx_pad-string-to-length.html), solves your problem in XQuery. Either import it as a module (its uri is stable), or google the function name.

```
declare namespace functx = "http://www.functx.com";
 declare function functx:pad-string-to-length
  ( $stringToPad as xs:string? ,
     $padChar as xs:string ,
     $length as xs:integer )  as xs:string {

    substring(
      string-join (
       ($stringToPad, for $i in (1 to $length) return $padChar)
       ,'')
    ,1,$length)
 } ;
```

see this fiddle: http://xqueryfiddle.liberty-development.net/jyyiVhe/2

Will generate the desired output but Oracle Jdev will not display it with proper spacing.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This code is working when I am generating a flat file from input xml. I want to generate xml out of the input xml to this Xquery. For example if the string is "hello", this code will give "hello "  if I pad two whitespaces in output flat file. But if I generate a output xml it will simply give "hello".

Comment: please update your question with a sample input, the transformation you are running, and the expected output. It s impossible to answer your question otherwise.

Comment: I am new to this site, updated the sample code with desired output inside same text area(sorry about that)

Comment: Welcome on !SO please see the fiddle in my response. The input you posted wasn't well formed so I fixed that, and removed the namespace to make it easier to read. Hope this answers your question.

Comment: thanks @duncdrum, I am working on Jdeveloper, and it behaves like I posted. But it is working in fiddle as expected.

Comment: In that case you need to make sure that the space preference of your parser is set to preserve.  see here for details http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/wang-whitespace-092897.html

Comment: I have "declare boundary - space preserve;" on top of the Xquery, still it is not working.